# Blender search language to english

Tags: settings

### Good time of a day ✌^_^ ! )

Are there any options to make default blender search in english while all the rest is on my native language? I mean if I have changed my language settings to my native language, then I can't search anything in english, I can only search on native language.
This is VERY UNCOMFORTABLE because I used to watch guides and read any faq on english, so when it comes to inputting any node I have to search for the exact word in native language, but I can't type it on english .

Help , please !

Wish You All the Graces !

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: You are learning Blender in English, why don't you simply use it in English? I'm not a native English speaker either, but this and other software sometimes only exists in English so I learn and use it like that. Some tool names do not make more sense to me in my language than in English anyway. And on sites like this where English is mandatory, it is sometimes not easy to understand what is going on in screenshots when everything is in a different language. Of course some things can be guessed, but others...

Comment: Man , bcs Blender has many modifiers that I have to translate to My language , other words I understand more without guides only bcs I can understand meaning of each name fast .